# Apostrophe while querying mysql

Tags: mysql, database, querying

I have a table that contains a string column with the value "I won't go"

I want to return this row whether that user is querying "I won't go" OR "I wont go" (without apostrophe).

How should I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: user is querying what do you mean ?

Comment: Seems to me you've answered your own question.

Comment: The user is querying for "I wont go" and I need a match with the db value of "I won't go", but I need a generic solution to all other cases like "I'd like", does mysql has a buit-in solution or that I need to use a regex that tells it to ignore apostrophe?

Comment: I mean, is there anything better than this: http://ben-major.co.uk/2012/12/mysql-searches-and-apostrophes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the single quote on both sides and just doing an equality comparison:

```
where replace(col, '''', '') = 'I wont go'
```